# How to solve Poisson's equation with incomplete knowledge of the right-hand side?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Consider the following [Poission equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation),
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\varphi(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z).$$
I was wondering if we can calculate a plane of values for $\varphi(x,y,z)$ if we only know $f(x,y,z)$ at a plane of values? In other words, can we calculate $\varphi(x,y,z_0)$ if we know that
$$f(x,y,z_0) = f_0(x,y)$$
but do not know the values of $f(x,y,z)$ $\forall z\ne z_0$?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Is it possible to say anything about $\varphi(x,y,z_0)$. Can we calculate it up to a scalar factor or something like that?

Comment: Are you hoping for something like "separation of variables"? You'd need _some_ info about the right-hand side...

Comment: One idea I thought of just now is to assume that $$\varphi(x,y,z) = \varphi(x,y,z_0) + (z-z_0)\varphi_z(x,y,z_0) + \frac{1}{2}(z-z_0)^2\varphi_{zz}(x,y,z_0) + ...,$$ and $$f(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z_0) + (z-z_0)f_z(x,y,z_0) + ...\,.$$

Comment: The first comment above still stands. It's a big no. A physical take on it: you are asking if you know the matter density along some plane through the earth than can you tell what the gravitational force is on that plane. The answer is a big no. One slice through the earth does not tell you the mass of the earth (and also does not tell you that there is a moon and sun in our solar-system).

Comment: In fact given a solution to Poissons equation for a given $f$ you are allowed to change $f$ to be *whatever you want* along a single plane (a infinitely thin plane has zero mass) and not change the solution at all! Thus you cannot say *anything at all* about the solution from just knowing it along one single plane.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'd still be interested if there are any properties we can say the solution must satisfy.

Comment: As I said above you cannot say anything. You can see this more directly by using Fourier transforms to formally write the solution as $\phi(x,y,z) = -\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{f(x',y',z')}{k^2}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')}\,d^3k\,d^3x'$ with $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ from which the same conclusion follows.

Comment: To answer your various questions: No. No. No. No. @Winther gave a simple _proof_ that you cannot say anything at all. Then you ask if there are any properties that _can_ be determined? Huh??? It's literally true that nothing whatever can be said.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help.